# No Resource found that matches the given name Xamarin Android

Tags: android, resources, xamarin, drawable

I always get the error "No Resource found that matches the given name" in my themes.xml file no matter which resource I use or in which  I use it. Even if the resource works everywhere else.

Here's some code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ActionBarOverflowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#008A3D</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarOverflowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/OverflowIcon</item>
    </style>


    <!--Dialog styles-->
    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">#008A3D</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I deleted the item node to check whether I can use the resource in code.
Proof that it worked; No error:

[image]

Comment: I thought it would be obvious as it's in the title. I guess I'm going to add it to the post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After googling and fiddling around for a few more hours I figured out that the problem was due to the fact that I use uppercase characters in the file name which works fine everywhere else. This is either a terrible behavior of Android or a bug in Xamarin.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's an Android rule!

Comment: It may be an android rule, but it should give a more descriptive exception. @AndreaBellitto

Comment: it's strange i have some layouts with UpperCase that work, but some don't... it's still a mistery for me.

Comment: It worked for me thanks! @k0bin It would help you if you mark your own answer as accepted, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that finds this question for different reasons:

Whenever I **Copy** or **Rename** a drawable resource in VS 2017, it changes the 'Build Action'.

Double check your resources, and ensure the Build Action is set correctly. In my case, it needed to be 'AndroidResource'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image from the project, clean the project, add the properly renamed image(don't try to rename the image once you have added to the project). Should work perfectly.